# Android:How create separate code from activity change

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I want to create download manager or music player

After click on play music or download file , seek bar is activated

To this episode , not a problem

But after click another item and go to new activity or press back and back to main activity , this seek bar is breaks !

How create code and activate UI without if change activity ?

See this  Levels :

Level 1 : [i.stack.imgur.com/yK3xq.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yK3xq.png)

Level 2 : [i.stack.imgur.com/02xJi.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02xJi.png)

Level 3 : [i.stack.imgur.com/ondXx.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ondXx.png)

Level 4 : [i.stack.imgur.com/zadk6.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zadk6.png)

Level 5 : [i.stack.imgur.com/32vOB.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32vOB.png)

Answer (score -1):

Utilize Volley and EventBus.

While Volley Downloads in the Back , Use EventBus to Publish Progress Informations for the UI.

Comment: These are big topics but will be useful for you in the long run. Learn Beginner Tutorials which would be enough here.